# Extracting Interface hide specifics of member if that's an interface too

Tags: c#

I have this class `Project` which I want to extract an interface out of, since we're going to work with different types of projects. One of the properties of `Project` however is called `Data`:

```
class Project {
    public Data D {get;}
    public void SomeSpecificMethodReferencingData() 
    { 
      D.SomeSpecificMethod(); 
    }
}

class Data {
   public void SomeGenericMethod() { }
   public void SomeSpecificMethod() { }
}
```

Now, `Data` needs to be extracted as an interface as well (but only defining the `SomeGenericMethod()`. I am currently using this:

```
interface IProject {
    IData D {get;}
}

interface IData {
    void SomeGenericMethod();
}

class Data : IData {
    public void SomeGenericMethod() { }
    public void SomeSpecificMethod() { }
}

class OtherData : IData {
    public void SomeGenericMethod() { }
    public int SomeOtherSpecificMethod(float someArgument) { }
}

class Project : IProject {
    public IData D { get; }
    public void SomeSpecificMethodReferencingData()
    { 
      D.SomeSpecificMethod(); // this does not work!
      (D as Data).SomeSpecificMethod(); // this looks stupid!
    }
}

class OtherProject : IProject {
    public IData D { get; }
    public void SomeOSpecificMethodReferencingOtherData()
    {
       var i = D.SomeOtherSpecificMethod(14.0f); // this does not work!
       var i = (D as OtherData).SomeOtherSpecificMethod(14.0f); // this looks stupid!
    }
}
```

The problem I run into is that within the `Project` class, I reference the `SomeSpecificMethod`. When I extract an interface for `Data` however, I first have to cast it from `IData` to be able to reference the specific method. This is not preferrable as the IData ALWAYS is an instance of Data for this Project. When I build my `OtherProject` I will create an `OtherData` for it, so to get pairs of xxxProject and xxxData implementations.

Is there a design pattern of some sort to help me building pairs of related and referenced classes? Like the Abstract Factory, but better?

Comment: Can you please show the troublesome code? The problem you are talking about is not clear.

Comment: If all your instance of `IData` actually are `Data`-objects, why does the interface contain only one member of that class? So either make another interface for that member and cast to that, or add the member to `IData` as well.

Comment: Did you consider using [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes)? Like `interface IProject<TData> where TData: IData` or something similar? Then you could have `class Project : IProject<Data>` ...

Comment: You are referencing `SomeSpecificMethod`. The point is this method is not defined in your interface `IData`. Only the concrete implementation has this method defined. That's why you have to cast to the implementation to access this method. Add the method `SomeSpecificMethod` to the interface as well.

Comment: Have you thought about having in each xxxProject: `private xxxData MyD => (xxxData)D;` - Also not very beautiful. The other thing I was thinking was: Could there be a conceptual problem, here? Is the logic behind `SomeSpecificMethod` really a concern of `Data` or is more specific to how `Project` should _handle_ `Data`? So, maybe other patterns should be considered, too? Like strategy pattern, factory, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use generics for that:

```
interface IProject<T> where T: IData {
    T D {get;}
}
```

Now your different projects are this:

```
class Project : IProject<Data> 
{
    public Data D { get; }
    public void SomeSpecificMethodReferencingData()
    { 
        D.SomeSpecificMethod();  // D is of type Data
    }
}

class OtherProject : IProject<OtherData> {
    public OtherData D { get; }
    public void SomeOSpecificMethodReferencingOtherData()
    {
         D.SomeOtherSpecificMethod(14.0f); // D is of type OtherData
    }
}
```

Comment: @BionicCode because...? From my point of view we need the specific stuff only within the specific project, which knows the type of data it belongs to.

Comment: The problem is that the member is not defined in the interface. `SomeSpecificMethod` doesn't exist in `IData`.

Comment: @BionicCode That´s not the problem, unless OP wants to use the `SomeSpecificMember` **outside** of `Project`, which he/she does not.

Comment: `SomeSpecificMethod` only exists in `Data´ that's why he needs the cast.

Comment: He expects to reference the method using the `IData` interface directly.

Comment: So I like Generics as a solution (it can solve this problem I believe). However, If I reference IProject somewhere else as a property in a class, That class needs to become a generic class as well, correct?

Comment: @BionicCode No, he is just not aware of Generics. That's why he used IData as member type. And that's why he _has_ that problem in the first place.

Comment: @BionicCode Obviously OP does not want to pollute `IData` with stuff specific to `Data`.

Comment: @Henri Yes, you have to know the projects `Data`-type at compile-time then. Or create a non-generic base-interface from which `IProject<T>` derives from

Comment: @HimBromBeere This question changed a lot. Initially nothing of this was communicated. He just couldn't reference `SomeSpecificMethod` when accessing an `IData` instance.

Comment: @BionicCode The edit just made the problem more visible. Before, you were making assumptions that simply weren't justified to be made.

Comment: @Fildor No that's not true. He posted his code. I asked him to show where the unexpected behavior exposes. He then updated the code to show his usage. I just responded to his rendered scenario. From this scenario it was obvious that he was trying to reference an interface member that was not declared while he was wondering why the cast to the implementation is necessary. Now after various updates he changed the scheme and we now know more and it now turns out that my understanding was wrong. But at the moment I answered everything was justified.

Comment: @Fildor While we had the discussion going on I didn't realized that he has already changed the question in the meantime. The misunderstanding was subject to the initial bad question.

Comment: @BionicCode I understand and accept that this is your perception. I have a different one. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: Guys sorry for my initial 'bad' question, I should have made more clear what my issue was with the example. I ended up using Generics since that made the most sense to me. It ensures that I have the correct Project and Data paired up.

Answer (score 1):

you can have 3 separate interfaces:

```
interface IData:ISpecificData, IGenericData
    {    
    }
    interface ISpecificData
    {
        void SomeSpecificMethod();
    }
    interface IGenericData
    {
        void SomeGenericMethod();
    }
```

you can use only one of the interfaces when you need only one of the methods, and use `IData` when you need both

Comment: Or (maybe better?) to have 2 interface - `IData` (with `SomeGenericMethod`) and `ISecificicData` (with `SomeSpecificMethod`) that inherits IData ?

Comment: How would that solve a `OtherProject.D.SomeOtherSpecificMethod(float)`? Notice the parameter for `SomeOtherSpecificMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

In class Project you are referencing SomeSpecificMethod of Data class.

You are NOT using anything from `IData` interface - so using `IData` in `Project` class has no sense.

It is possible to do it as in your examples, and it will work - but it is "wrong way".

```
  (D as Data).SomeSpecificMethod(); // this looks stupid!
```

It looks stupid - but from other reasons. What if `D` is not `Data`, but `OtherData` ? It will be perfectly correct at compile time, but it will blow up during runtime!

Comment: "What if D is not Data, but OtherData ? It will be perfectly correct at compile time, but it will blow up during runtime!" I'm aware of that, so ideally I want to use `Data` as property, but then I'm not implementing the interface anymore (it needs to implement IData since I need the `IProject.D.SomeGenericMethod`  call)